# Permissions for Assets folder to avoid Javascript Attacks? YII and Ubuntu

Tags: security, ubuntu, yii2, assets

Today i got to know that one of my websites(developed in Yii2) has been attacked by malware. Whenever i clicked on any link, a new tab opened. Also, my website has been blacklisted by Baracuda. 
To probe this, i deleted all asset files in assets folder. After this the redirection stopped and new tabs stopped opening. I reckon there is some problem with the permission of Assets folder.

Question:

1. Whether it could be the issue of permissions or anything else?
2. If it is permissions then what should be the permissions of Assets folder? right now i have 777
3. What else can I do to make my website more secure against Javascript attacks?

Comment: I guess before to move to production you have to run console `init` and chose `prod` mode, and that will make the right permissions, other than that, common used permissions for files are `644` and folders `755`, also consider set the proper user/owner `www-data` on all files and folders, so nobody be able to modify the folder and files.

Comment: not sure if it has to do anything with yii

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i agree with that, i have mentioned yii bcz yii creates assets files on runtime. So it needs the write permission